# How to pip install pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

D:\sanghoclaptrinh\python\Baymax>pip install pyaudio

D:\sanghoclaptrinh\python\Baymax>pip install pyaudio
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in c:\users\ho sang\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.2.11)

D:\sanghoclaptrinh\python\Baymax>nghe.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ho Sang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\sanghoclaptrinh\python\Baymax\nghe.py", line 4, in 
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Ho Sang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 80, in **init**
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Ho Sang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: You have multiple Python version. It is being installed to Python 3.10 but you are executing Python 3.11. Either adjust your project to Python 3.10 or install it in Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check out this blog on installing pyaudio > https://pythonpoint.net/how-to-install-pyaudio-in-python/

Tip: Install PyAudio using Administrator CMD.

Comment: same bro :< help me :<

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python 3.11.4 {microsoft store version} and works fine.

you can download it [here](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/python-311/9NRWMJP3717K).

Answer (score -1):

Birinchi navbatda pythonni o'rnating keyin esa uni system path ga qo'shing , agar sizda pip is not recognized xatosi kelib chiqsa python o'rnatilishidan oldin pip oldiga tasdiqlash belgisini bosib o'rnating. win+r ->  cmd -> pip install pyaudio. Bu ishlarni qilganingizdan keyin pyaudio paketi o'rnatilishi kerak

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your answer should be in English.